# How to retrieve values from database in asp.net using web service?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have made a login form on asp.net and i want to retrieve first name and last name from the database that matches email address. I am using a web service for this purpose. What query should i b using? The database that i have created is on the web service and all of the web pages are made on the client.

Comment: There needs to be a lot more details to get an answer. You're asking for a query but have provided no information about your database. If you're making this call via a web service, that hides the database schema in favour of a model, but there is no mention of what web service technology you are using. What else have you tried? What errors are you seeing? All helps to get you an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, we don't know all the specifics, the following is the general idea on how to solve your problem.  You can add code similar to this in your web service provided that you have access to the database there.   Although I am assuming an asmx web service, the same idea would apply to WCF.

```
public struct User
        {
            public string FirstName;
            public string LastName;
        }

[WebMethod]
public User GetUser(string emailAddress)
{
    string first = string.Empty;
    string last = string.Empty;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
         connection.Open();
         var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
         sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

         // modify query to match actual table and column names
         sqlCommand.CommandText = "select firstName, lastName from users where email=@email";
         sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", emailAddress));
         var sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while(sqlReader.Read())
            {
                first = sqlReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                last = sqlReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            }
        }

        // returns empty strings if no record is found
        return new User { FirstName = first, LastName = last };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about query than you can write a query like this

```
select first_name,last_name from table where email_address='emailaddresstomatch'
```

Comment: and where do i write this query?

Comment: In webservice as you said you are using webservice for this.